# Black Border on Windows 7 display

Tags: windows-7, graphics

I just installed windows 7 and found that I have a black border around my display space (it persists across various resolution levels). What I found on the internet implies that I should adjust the scaling but the scaling bar is greyed out. In addition, the resources I found were "underscannned" before the fix but my bar is moved all the way to the "overscan" end. Anyone know of a solution?

I'm using an AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series Graphics Card and have the ASUS ML228 Monitor.

Comment: How thick is the border? Is it covering up anything on the screen?

Comment: It's not covering anything. The display space is containing the right information but it isn't using the entire screen. I'm not a great judge of distance w/ measurements but the top and bottom of the black border are half as tall as the left and right are thick.

Comment: Have you tried stretching the picture on your screen out using the controls on your monitor? On my monitor it is in Menu -> Size & Position -> Horizontal Stretch and Vertical Stretch.

Comment: There's no "Size & Position" option in my monitor menu.

Comment: Hmm, next I would try updating to the latest AMD Catalyst video drivers. You can find them at http://support.amd.com/en-us/download. Once they are downloaded and installed go back into the Windows CP and set the resolution to 1920x1080. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I had already updated the driver because my computer wasn't properly detecting my graphics card correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I restarted my computer and when I booted back up the scaling option was working correctly.

Comment: I'm glad it got fixed. Enjoy your new system man. :)